# Xamarin/Prism Issue with Oppo Phones with overlapping Screen

Tags: android, xamarin, prism, oppo

I'm encountering issues with Oppo phones using Xamarin with Prism. As included in the attached screenshot, the screens overlap as if their background is transparent. I have difficulties debugging the issue because it is perfectly fine in my phone (Redmi Note 8 Pro - Android 11).

The phone in the screenshot is Oppo F7 Android 10.

Any leads or hints on things to investigate that will guide me to the solution would help!

[Screenshot of the overlapping screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/v5u6K.png)